# Mysql deleting rows not in other table

Tags: mysql

I know this is possible, but not when you need to reference the row you want to delete from. For example:

```
select * from `dvd_role` r
left join `dvd_actor2role` a on a.`roleId` = r.id
where a.roleId is null;
```

This produces the offending rows which are not present in the dvd_actor2role table and I want to delete. But I cannot use the dvd_role table in the subquery or I get an error, yet I need that table to be able to determine which rows to delete.

Is there a workaround for this within SQL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Left join and checking for null at the "right limb" seems a pathology these days. Use NOT EXISTS instead.

```
SELECT *
FROM dvd_role r
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT * FROM dvd_actor_role a
   WHERE a.roleId = r.id
   );
```

If all is well replace the first "select *" by a DELETE.

Comment: I ended up doing this: `DELETE FROM dvd_role WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT roleId FROM dvd_actor2role);` which I believe is the same as you have there, but maybe yours is faster?

Comment: I guess the IS NULL thing is because it's faster than NOT EXISTS? Thanks for the answer by the way.

Comment: Faster is not an issue. Theoretically, they are equal. (there is a small semantic difference, caused by three-valued logic involved). The query resolves to: there are two kinds of rows in dvd_role: those that exist in dvd_actor_role, and those that don't. Both queries perform this task. But the LEFT JOIN does this rather clumsily: by finding all the matching records form dvd_actor_role, or by finding a dummy match if none exists, and than testing for the dummy. (a query optimiser will probably strip this down, but it seems illogical to first match and than drop the matched ones)